# We want to change the colour of the model with passing the DBId without selection. #AutodeskForge

Tags: colors, model, autodesk-forge

In 3d Model of Autodesk Forge, We want to change the colour of the model with passing the DBId without selection. How can we do it? please help on this.. we are unable to find any reference on this.

Comment: setThemingColor is working when the selectionChanged() event is fired. we want to change the color without any selection. by just passing the DBid .Eveything works inside selectionChange. i want change the colour as soon as the model is loaded. without any selection .

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a dbID of an object you'd like to color, you can use the viewer's [setThemingColor](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Viewing/Viewer3D/#setthemingcolor-dbid-color-model-recursive) method.

If you're asking about how to get dbIDs of objects without selecting them, there are different ways. For example, you can iterate through the scene hierarchy (as explained in this [blog post](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/working-2d-and-3d-scenes-and-geometry-forge-viewer)), or obtain dbIDs of objects with specific properties (using the [getProperties](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Viewing/Viewer3D/#getproperties-dbid-onsuccesscallback-onerrorcallback) method).